# In how many ways can a six digit number(no repetition) be formed such that sum is odd.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can a six digit number (no repetition) be formed such that sum is odd.

My approach: 
It can be divided into the following cases, 
1 odd and 5 even,  3 odd and 3 even, 5 odd and 1 even.

Second approach: 
$$\frac{\binom{10}{6}\cdot6!}{2} $$
Is it correct, or is there an easier alternative?

Comment: If you have two odd numbers and four even numbers... what is the sum?

Comment: Yes, apologies, will strike it out.

Comment: I'm guessing you aren't allowed a leading zero

Comment: Im aware of elementary combinatorics, how can we arrange for that condition?

Answer (score 3):

Since $\frac9{10}$ of the numbers will **not** have  leading zeroes, the simplest way is to multiply your second formulation by $0.9$, thus

answer $= \dfrac{^{10}C_6\cdot6!\cdot 0.9}{2},\;\;$ or more succinctly, $\;\;0.45\times^{10}P_6$

Answer (score 2):

Your second approach is including $6$ digit numbers which start with $0$.

Remove numbers having $0$ in their starting place. $$= \frac{^9C_5\cdot5!}{2}$$

Total ways:
$$= \frac{^{10}C_6\cdot6!}{2}- \frac{^9C_5\cdot5!}{2}$$

---

The another approach for verifying would be counting the numbers which don't have $0$ in them.$$= \frac{^9C_6\cdot6!}{2}$$

And then also considering the numbers which have $0$ but not in starting place. We can place $0$ in five positions(i.e. $\times\ \_\ \_\ \_\ \_\ \_\ $) and the remaining $5$ digits can be arranged in leftover five positions.$$= \frac{5\cdot\ ^9C_5\cdot5!}{2}$$

Total number of ways is
$$= \frac{^9C_6\cdot6!}{2}+ \frac{5\cdot\ ^9C_5\cdot5!}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint -

You have to solve it for different cases and then add them.

Case 1 -  5 are even and 1 odd.

Case 2 - 3 are even and 3 are odd.

Case 3 - 1 is even and 5 are odd.

Also second method you are using is not correct. As includes numbers with starting digit 0, case with all digits even and all digits odd.